# iPhone - Compiling on older SDK : __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED values

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, preprocessor, backwards-compatibility

I need test some stuff with preprocessor tests to ensure backward compatibility for my app.
To do this, I must use __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= xxx but does someone know where I can find the values to test for each existing SDK ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you command-click on `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` (in Xcode) you'll see the current definition (in `AvailabilityInternal.h`) for the current SDK and the older SDK.

They are basically `__IPHONE_4_3`, `__IPHONE_4_2`, `__IPHONE_4_1`, `__IPHONE_4_0`, `__IPHONE_3_0`, etc.